# Css selectors SharePoint 2010

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following html structure:

```
<div class="ms-PostFooter">

<span style="">
<span style="" class="s4-clust">
<a href="#" style="">
<img src="" alt="" style="l" title="" class="imglink" longDesc="" />
</a>
</span>
</span>

<span style="">
<span class="s4-clust">
<a href="#" style="">
<img src="" alt="" style="" title="" class="imglink" longDesc="" />
</a>
</span>
</span>

<span style="">
<span class="s4-clust">
<a href="#" style="">
<img src="" alt="" style="" title="Number of Comments" class="imglink" longDesc="" />
</a>
</span>
</span>

</div>
```

In css how would I select the third  tag in order to hide the image with title "Number of Comments"?

Comment: apply a class which has `display:none` property to your img tag

Comment: I would do that but I do not want to go and edit the HTML.... that would involve making changes to branding project then deploy which would be overkill in this instance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.ms-PostFooter span::nth-child(3) img {
    display: none;
}
```

or this also works:

```
img[title="Number of Comments"] {
    display: none;
}
```

however these rely on your markup / content. the best way would be - generate a specific class on that image or its container, server-side (if you can)

Comment: Hi Luca the img selector above worked, however I've noticed that the link is still there although the image has now been hidden. How would I hide the entire third <span> tag instead?

Comment: @DanielPerez if you remove `img` from the first option in my answer, it will hide the entire third `<span>` tag :)

Answer (score 0):

One possibility if your title is unique:

```
[title="Number of Comments"]
{
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
div :last-child span .imglink{
   display:none;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kGThS/1/

This may be more specific:

```
.ms-PostFooter :last-child span .imglink{
   display:none;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kGThS/3/

To hide the entire last span/link as per your comment below use the following:

```
.ms-PostFooter :last-child span{
   display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow through css sharepoint was not allowing me to use any of the selectors mentioned here through css to get rid of the specif  tag containing the link and image to be removed so I decided to use jquery instead which did the trick as follows:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('DIV.ms-PostFooter span:nth-child(3)').css('display', 'none');
$('DIV.ms-PostFooter span:nth-child(4)').css('display', 'none');

});
```

Thanks for all the assistance.